# Continue url match if request is not resolved - Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I'm not sure if it's very specific but I think what I am going to ask is being used in various places in different contexts. My problem is mainly related to URL patterns that I've created for my Django application. I need a profile URL for all application users, so I am creating a URL pattern as below.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('apps.user_profile.views',
    url(r"^(?P<username>\w+)/$", 'user_profile', name="user_profile_page"),
    url(r"^app/$", 'app', name="app_page"),
)
```

As is very clear, I am mapping URLs with user names in the path to fetch user data dynamically. This is working fine, but the problem comes when the system gets a request for `app` page. In this case, the request goes to user profile, since it accepts all kinds of words and is ordered before `app` view in `urls.py`.

**Question :**
Is there any way to specify, where a request is not resolved in `user_profile` view, to continue looking at other URLs in the `urls.py` of app?

Answer (score 0):

Patterns are matched in the order they are written, so simply moving your `app` pattern before your username pattern will solve your problem:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('apps.user_profile.views',
    url(r"^app/$", 'app', name="app_page"),
    url(r"^(?P<username>\w+)/$", 'user_profile', name="user_profile_page"),

)
```

Now, only if a url *doesn't* match `app/` it will be sent to your user profile view.

Of course, you will have an issue the day a user signs up with the username of `app`.

Comment: Changing the regex to ``^users/(?P<username>\w+)/$`` could help with that. Or better yet, mapping ``^users/`` to another ``urls.py`` and here use ``(?P<username>\w+)/$``.

Comment: @burhan: I can put app before user profile url but in that case it will affect the other app's url in my project which comes after `user_profile` app.

Comment: @xbello Yeah I can keep it to `^users/(?P<username>\w+)/$` but is there no other way to achieve. It looks very common functionality.

Comment: Put your username profile URL as the last URL, because it matches any URL.

Comment: @lalit, what you ask for is to put url dispatchers in view functions, i.e. an ``user_profile()`` that calls ``app()`` function if the url starts with "app". I think it's possible, but your code will be broken from the beginning. Use the Django dispatcher. Look at the urls in stackoverflow: they begin with the "app" name (user, questions, tags, unanswered...) making it very easy to extend the site.